# How to remove Teams banner from right bottom corner of SharePoint site?

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, administration, microsoft-teams

I want to remove annoying Teams banner/tab from right down corner of SharePoint site.

Comment: Can you share screenshot of banner message you are talking about? Are you talking about option at bottom "left" corner (below left navigation) on SharePoint team sites?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to hide the Microsoft Teams option (as given in below image) from SharePoint team site, you can use PowerShell for it:

[image]

Use PowerShell like:

```
#Variables
$SiteURL = "https://crescent.sharepoint.com/sites/Credit"
 
#Connect to PnP Online
Connect-PnPOnline -URL $SiteURL -Interactive
 
#Update the Property bag key to remove Teams Prompt
Set-PnPPropertyBagValue -Key "TeamifyHidden" -Value "True"
```

**Source**: [How to Disable Microsoft Teams “Create a Team” Prompt in SharePoint Online?](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2019/07/disable-microsoft-teams-popup-in-sharepoint-online.html)

**Note**: You have to Enable custom scripting in SharePoint Online prior before using above script. Check: [Allow use of custom scripts in SharePoint Online using PowerShell](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/05/18/allow-use-of-custom-scripts-in-sharepoint-online-using-powershell/).